# Xcode Data Controller Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, controller

I have an application that has the following parts:

- StoreDataController.h
- StoreDataController.m
- StoreTableViewController.h
- StoreTableViewController.m

I created a property & method in StoreDataController that retrieves data from a URL and converts it to JSON. I then store it in an Array. I'm trying to get the table controller to display the array in the table but it isn't displaying. What do I need to do to have the Table display the contents of the array? Here is the code I have:

StoreDataController.h

```
@interface StoreDataController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *storeNames;
-(void)addStoreNamesObject:(NSArray *)storeNames;
@end
```

StoreDataController.m

```
#import "StoreDataController.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

@implementation StoreDataController

-(void)addStoreNamesObject:(NSArray *)storeNames
{
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.247.245.87/stores/dodge.php"];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
storeNames = [strResult JSONValue];
}
@end
```

StoreTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class StoreDataController;

@interface StoreTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) StoreDataController *storeNameController;
@end
```

StoreTableViewController.m

```
#import "StoreTableViewController.h"
#import "StoreDataController.h"

@interface StoreTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation StoreTableViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _storeNameController.storeNames.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [_storeNameController.storeNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You at least need something to set the `storeNameController` property inside your `StoreTableViewController` so that it references the `StoreDataController` object that is doing the work of building the array.

How you do that depends on what creates the `StoreDataController` object and how that's related to your view controller.

(Aside: In general, you should use `self.propertyName` instead of `_propertyName`.)

Comment: Im having a hard time making sense of what you said. I got the "Aside" note and thanks for the tip:-)

When you say I need something to set the `storeNameController` property inside of the `StoreTableViewController`, what "something" could I use?

Comment: I was looking through the code and from what I can see, isn't the `storeNameController` property already inside of `StoreTableViewController`? Look at the `StoreTableViewController.h` file.

Comment: Presumably there's somewhere that you create a `StoreDataController` and call `addStoreNamesObject:`.  (?)  The object that does that would be a good candidate.  (As a sanity check, put `NSLog(@"Data controller: %@", self.storeNameController);` inside your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method and see what it prints.)

Comment: The @property line just says that there exists a variable named `storeNameController` which can point to an object of the `StoreTableViewController` type.  It doesn't create the object nor assign it to the variable.

Comment: The `StoreDataController` creates the object doesn't it? the `NSArray` called `storeNames`?

Comment: I assume `[strResult JSONValue]` is creating an array, though I'm not a JSON person and can't say for sure.  (Even that's odd because you're passing `storeNames` as a parameter and also have a `storeNames` property.  I suggest getting rid of the parameter and using `self.storeNames` instead.)  Anyway, even if that creates the array, it doesn't answer the question of what creates the `StoreDataController` object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18922/discussion-between-charles-vincent-and-phillip-mills)